# Emacs: How to continue buffer contents in another window?

Tags: emacs, window, buffer

My screen is short but wide. Is there a way to left/right split the screen, while the end of left buffer is the starting of right buffer, and kept locked in this way while browsing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's what [`follow-mode`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Follow-Mode.html) is for and does.